# to find the graphs having vertices with same eccentricity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, tensor-products

I was reading a paper

http://www.discuss.wmie.uz.zgora.pl/php/discuss3.php?ip=&url=plik&nIdA=11134&sTyp=HTML&nIdSesji=-1

There is a formula to calculate eccentricity in the section 4.

[image]

where $E_G(x) = max\{D_G(x, y)|y\in V(G)\}$ and $D_G(x, y)$ is the
minimum length of an *x-y* walk whose parity differs from that of $d_G(x, y)$. Also Two walks have the same parity if the difference of their lengths is even; otherwise they have opposite parity.

I was just looking for those graphs where eccentricity comes out to be the same. One of my attempts made me to think that if we take all graphs as cycles of odd length, then eccentricity of every vertex in the tensor product will be same. Am I right? Are there any other conditions or graphs so that we get the required condition. If not then please help me by giving hints or suggestions. Thanks a lot for helping and giving time. Thanks

***Note:*** The reason of taking cycles of odd length is that we can easily find odd and even length walks between any pair of vertices in a graph.